# How can I place brackets around a field in a view?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'd like to place a field's value in a view between brackets. Let's say that there are 2 fields 'Name' and 'Country'. How can I display these as **Name (Country)** in a view? I know how to inline the fields, but I have no idea how to place the brackets around the second field.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look for "rewrite field" option.

Comment: Thanks @Mołot! That's the answer! Didn't know it would be that simple. I'll check it as 'answer' if you submit it.

Comment: @Mołot: do you also know how I can become the same result for a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the **rewrite field** option: use the 'country' token and place brackets around it.

Special thanks to @Mołot!